# Get response status after every controller is executed in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a RoR Rest API and I want to emit a metric with the status of each response of my API. I managed to do that for all the cases except from those where the controller is crashing.

For example with the following code in the ApplicationController:

```
require 'statsd-ruby'

class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  after_action :push_status_metric

  def push_status_metric
    statsd = Statsd.new ENV['STATSD_LOCATION'], ENV['STATSD_PORT']
    puts normalize_status_metric(response.status)

    statsd.increment('ds.status.' + normalize_status_metric(response.status).to_s + '.int') unless request.fullpath == '/health'
  end

  private

  def normalize_status_metric(status)
    return 100 if status >= 100 && status < 200
    return 200 if status >= 200 && status < 300
    return 300 if status >= 300 && status < 400
    return 400 if status >= 400 && status < 500
    return 500 if status >= 500 && status < 600
    0
  end
end
```

But this solution doesn't capture errors such as ActionController::RoutingError and ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.

I tried the following code:

```
  rescue_from StandardError do |exception|
    statsd = Statsd.new ENV['STATSD_LOCATION'], ENV['STATSD_PORT']
    statsd.increment('ds.status.' + normalize_status_metric(response.status).to_s + '.int') unless request.fullpath == '/health'

    raise exception
  end
```

But when this callback is executed, the response.status value is always 200 (seems like it's not set yet by the framework up to this point).

Comment: No, don't use this type of code snippets for ruby code. It's for runnable JS only (possibly with some html/css)

Comment: Yes I noticed it, but I didn't find a way to change the language of the snippet

Comment: There is no way, so don't use those. Instead, indent by 4 spaces.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks!

Comment: Me, I prepare all my code in an external editor (textmate). When I'm ready to paste the code, I do `cmd+A` (select all), `cmd+]` twice (indent), `cmd+C` (copy). Then paste into stackoverflow editor. :)

Comment: Rack middleware might help with that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Knowing the the rails logger manages to do this, we can take a look at its class, [`ActionController::LogSubscriber`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/log_subscriber.rb) and that `process_action` method. So, the status in that event could be `nil`, and we can see how they then convert an exception to a status, if an exception exists:

```
status = payload[:status]
if status.nil? && payload[:exception].present?
  exception_class_name = payload[:exception].first
  status = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.status_code_for_exception(exception_class_name)
end
```

So now, we can do something similar by subscribing to this event on our own, with [Active Support Instrumentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#subscribing-to-an-event), by creating an initializer:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe 'process_action.action_controller' do |*args|
  event = ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event.new(*args)

  # opening a file here is probably a performance nightmare, but you'd be doing something with statsd, not a file, anyway
  open('metrics.txt', 'a') do |f|
    # get the action status, this code is from the ActionController::LogSubscriber
    status = event.payload[:status]

    if status.nil? && event.payload[:exception].present?
      exception_class_name = event.payload[:exception].first

      status = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.status_code_for_exception(exception_class_name)
    end

    f.puts "process_action.action_controller controller: #{event.payload[:controller]} - action: #{event.payload[:action]} - path: #{event.payload[:path]} - status: #{status}"
  end
end
```

and hitting it a few times with a simple controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def non_standard_status
    render html: 'This is not fine', status: :forbidden
  end

  def error
    raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, 'No Records Found'
  end

  def another_error
    raise ArgumentError, 'Some Argument is wrong'
  end

  def this_is_fine
    render html: 'This is fine'
  end
end
```

yields a file:

```
process_action.action_controller controller: HomeController - action: non_standard_status - path: /forbidden - status: 403
process_action.action_controller controller: HomeController - action: error - path: /error - status: 404
process_action.action_controller controller: HomeController - action: another_error - path: /error2 - status: 500
process_action.action_controller controller: HomeController - action: this_is_fine - path: /fine - status: 200
```

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks for the solution and the great explanation!

Comment: ha, I learned a few things too, by getting curious about a question. :) +1

Answer (score 2):

> But when this callback is executed, the response.status value is always 200 (seems like it's not set yet by the framework up to this point).

Correct, it's not yet set (application didn't attempt to render). Normally, it's the `rescue_from` handler that will render the "error" response, with code and everything.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to grab the response status after it's set in the cases where a StandardError has been raised?

Comment: @Panos Off the top of my head, there's no appropriate framework hook. Maybe you could achieve something with overriding/wrapping `render`.

Comment: If you run this in an `around_action` with an `ensure` block, shouldn't the status have gotten set? but it's *always* 200 when there was an exception >.>